# Colormap from white to red

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a colormap that transitions slowly from white to red.

I have not found any colormaps that already do this online. If you guys know of one could you let me know?

Additionally, if there isn't one already made, how would I go about coding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"Reds" under sequential colormaps [Colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: Thanks! Reds seems to do the trick

Comment: For Reds, the color for zero is actually slightly off white and becomes dark for higher values. If anyone needs to get something going white to red, and no more then you could create a camp with rgb values of `(1, 1-x, 1-x)` where x ranges from 0 to 1.